# Deploy crystal reports on IIs 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, crystal-reports

I've got a problem while I'm configuring my web site in IIs 7, when I see the web I have this error:
[image]

I've already installed the redistributable and change allow aplications 32 bits to true, what do I need? I'm really desperate with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Crystal report dlls to the [bin] directory of the web application.